# Error en consultas de suma sqlServer

Tags: sql-server

## Pregunta original:

Tengo esta consulta y quiero hacer una suma de la columna "Importe" tomando en cuenta de una fecha inicial a una fecha final pero no se hace la suma y tambien me sale un error con la fecha

```
set dateformat dmy 
select f.folio as Folio, f.transaccion as Transaccion, f.Cod_Estab, sum(l.importe) as Importe, 
       f.fecha as Fecha , l.forma_pago , fp.nombre 
from facremtick f 
     inner join liquidaciones_tickets l on f.folio = l.ticket and f.transaccion = l.transaccion 
     left join formas_pago fp on fp.forma_pago = l.forma_Pago 
--where folio = '1178086 ' 
where l.forma_Pago = 3 and f.fecha between '2019/08/01' and '2019/08/31' and f.cod_estab = 1 
group by f.folio, f.transaccion, f.Cod_Estab, f.fecha, l.forma_pago , fp.nombre 
order by folio desc
```

## Edición:

Ya pude con lo de la fecha pero no me arroja el resultado de la sumatoria cambie la query de este modo

```
set dateformat dmy 
select sum(l.importe) as Importe 
from facremtick f 
inner join liquidaciones_tickets l on f.folio = l.ticket and f.transaccion = l.transaccion 
left join formas_pago fp on fp.forma_pago = l.forma_Pago 
where l.forma_Pago = 3 and f.fecha >= '1/08/2019' and f.fecha <='31/08/2019' and f.cod_estab = 1 order by folio desc
```

y el resultado que me manda es `NULL` pero si quito toda la fecha ya me manda la suma pero necesito sacarla por la fecha, ¿alguien me puede ayudar?.

Comment: Nos compartes por favor cuál es el error que te sale

Comment: Si tienes algún tipo de captura para poder visualizar el error que estas cometiendo.

Comment: sabes lo que significa poner dateformat dmy?, significa que le estás diciendo a SQL Server que cuando escribas una fecha, primero va el día, luego el mes y luego el año....ahora mira cómo le estás pasando las fechas en el `BETWEEN`

Comment: El error de la fecha se da porque estás utilizando un formato que depende de los valores configurados de fecha o lenguaje. Para evitar estos problemas, es importante que cuando vayas a usar cadenas para representar fechas lo hagas en formatos universales. Los formatos universales son `YYYYMMDD`, `YYYYMMDD hh:mi:ss.mss` y `YYYY-MM-DDThh:mi:ss.msss`. En el último formato, la T es muy importante para que sea correcto, y sólo el primer formato funciona para fechas sin hora.

Comment: El error dice que la convercion de un dato tipo varchar a un dato de tipo datetime resulta en un rango de valor out-of.  Esta query ya estaba echa funcionado bien solo que yo le quiero agregar que sume los valores del importe pero me sale este error con la fecha

Comment: Manuel, si al editar la pregunta eliminas todo el contexto, entonces ya no se entiende que es lo que viene pasando. La idea es que la pregunta se entienda siempre, por favor lee [ask]. Lo que he hecho es recuperar la pregunta original, ya que lo que dejaste luego de editar no tiene mucho sentido. Sugiero, en preguntas de este tipo, incluir una muestra de los datos de entrada y la salida que deseas obtener con dichos datos. No tienen por que ser muchos registros, con unos cuantos suele ser suficiente.

Comment: Disculpa soy nuevo a qui a si que no se como usar al 100 esta plataforma, pero checare la documentación, solo en esta ocasion ocupo tener la suma del importe por medio de fechas, por ejemplo en el where tengo **where l.forma_Pago = 3 and f.cod_estab = 1** con esta parte de la consulta me arroja la suma del importe pero cuando pongo **where l.forma_Pago = 3 and f.cod_estab = 1' and f.fecha >= '1/08/2019' and f.fecha <='31/08/2019'** ya no me hace la sumatoria solo me aparece null.  Solo quiero tener la suma pero con todo los parámetros del where incluyendo la fecha. no se si me explico.